# Erro ao executar aplicação (UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name )

Tags: java, spring-boot

Alguém pode me ajudar sobre o erro apresentado ao tentar executar a aplicação?

Erro:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reqSituacaoRecurso': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'reqSituacaoServico'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reqSituacaoServico': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'reqSituacaoRepositorio'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reqSituacaoRepositorio': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List br.jus.trf5.repositorio.customizado.ReqSituacaoRepositorioCustomizado.filter(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String)! No property filter found for type ReqSituacao!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro se refere a nomenclatura que você adotou para sua classe `ReqSituacaoRepositorioCustomizado` favor renomear sua Interface para `ReqSituacaoRepositorioCustom` e a Classe que implementa para `ReqSituacaoRepositorioImpl` pois por padrão o Spring espera que esta sufixo seja `Custom` para Interface e a classe de Implementação para `Impl`.

Comment: Funcionou tudo perfeito!