# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERROR

Tags: java, spring-boot

Erro completo:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationStart': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void br.com.backSpringBoot.awesome.repository.LoginRepository.delete(java.lang.Long)! No property delete found for type Login!
```

Estou criando os métodos HTTP para minha classe Login, e me deparei com este erro, e não consigo saber como solucionar!!! Alguém entende deste erro ?

Login.java:

```
@Entity
public class Login extends AbstractEntity {
    private String empresa;
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;   

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

EndpointLogin.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("login")
public class EndpointLogin {

    private final LoginRepository loginDAO;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointLogin(LoginRepository loginDAO) {
        this.loginDAO = loginDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> listAllLogin() {
        // System.out.println("DATA AQUI"+dateUtil.formatLocalDateTimeToDatabaseStyle(LocalDateTime.now()));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(loginDAO.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getLoginById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
       Login login = loginDAO.findOne(id);
        if (login == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new CustomErrorType("Login não encontrado"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(login, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }   

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody Login login) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(loginDAO.save(login), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path ="/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        loginDAO.delete(id);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Login login) {
        loginDAO.save(login);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

LoginRepository.java:

```
public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository<Login, Long> {
    List<Login> findByEmpresa(String empresa);
    List<Login> findByUsuario(String usuario);
    List<Login> findBySenha(String senha);

    public Login findOne(Long id);

    public void delete(Long id);
}
```

AbstractEntity.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final AbstractEntity other = (AbstractEntity) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se este caso te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/erro-ao-executar-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean

Comment: mudei o nome da classe, mas não resolveu o erro :/

Comment: Você chegou a anotar a interface LoginRepository com @Repository ?

Comment: @DiegoAguiar é eu tinha esquecido disso! Mas agora me vem outro erro.... 
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: id"

Comment: Anote a classe `LoginRepository` com `@Repository`, remova o método delete. Ultilize o método: `loginDAO.deleteById(id)`. Ele já vai estar implementado pela biblioteca.